# How to integrate premium responsive html template to umbraco?

Tags: html, cms, template, integration

How to integrate premium responsive html template to umbraco?

I have been wondering, that whether there is any kind of set of standards

OR

Any additional code to integrate my premium html web template to umbraco cms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umbraco uses standard HTML markup so you should be able to use pretty much all HTML templates, responsive is just clever styling and it'll work with correct markup with the template you have no problem.

You should take a look at:

http://umbracohosting.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/introduction-to-umbraco/sitebuilder-introduction/templates

http://www.blogfodder.co.uk/2010/5/13/building-your-first-umbraco-site-from-scratch

There's a few videos on Blogfodder which are really easy to follow and this should help you adapt the HTML template you have to work with Umbraco.